# How to add the chapter number into the chapter title using memoir class?

Tags: memoir, chapters

I want to add the chapter number into the chapter name.

[image]

To have something like that

[image]

I used these commands to remove the word chapter and the number :

```
\renewcommand\printchaptername{\chapnamefont} 
\renewcommand\printchapternum{\chapnumfont}
```

[EDIT] Here is the complete code :

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{times}

\usepackage[frenchb]{babel} %français

\usepackage[
breaklinks=true,colorlinks=true,
%linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=blue,% PDF VIEW
linkcolor=black,urlcolor=black,citecolor=black,% PRINT
bookmarks=true,bookmarksopenlevel=2]{hyperref}

\usepackage{geometry}
% PDF VIEW
% \geometry{total={210mm,297mm},
% left=25mm,right=25mm,%
% bindingoffset=0mm, top=25mm,bottom=25mm}
% PRINT
\geometry{total={210mm,297mm},
left=20mm,right=20mm,
bindingoffset=10mm, top=25mm,bottom=25mm}

\OnehalfSpacing
%\linespread{1.3}

%%% CHAPTER'S STYLE
\chapterstyle{bianchi}

%%% STYLE OF SECTIONS, SUBSECTIONS, AND SUBSUBSECTIONS


\renewcommand\printchaptername{\chapnamefont}
\renewcommand\printchapternum{\chapnumfont}

%%% STYLE OF PAGES NUMBERING
%\pagestyle{companion}\nouppercaseheads 
%\pagestyle{headings}
%\pagestyle{Ruled}
\pagestyle{plain}
\makepagestyle{plain}
\makeevenfoot{plain}{\thepage}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{plain}{}{}{\thepage}
% Possibilité de choisir ou se trouve le numéro de page, sur les pages pairs et impairs
\makeevenhead{plain}{}{}{}
\makeoddhead{plain}{}{}{}


\maxsecnumdepth{subsection} % chapters, sections, and subsections are numbered
\maxtocdepth{subsection} % chapters, sections, and subsections are in the Table of Contents


%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%
\usepackage[nosectionbib]{apacite}
\begin{document}

%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%
%   TITLEPAGE
%
%   due to variety of titlepage schemes it is probably better to make titlepage manually
%
%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%
\thispagestyle{empty}

{%%%
\sffamily
\centering
\large

~\vspace{\fill}

{\huge 
 \textbf{Thesis title: may be long or short}
}

\vspace{2.5cm}

{\Large
Mathieu
}

\vspace{3.5cm}
\textit{
Mémoire présenté pour l'obtention du titre de \\
\emph{blablablabalbalbalab}} \\
~\\
Universitéy liege \\
Faculté des sciences\\
Département


\vspace{3.5cm}

Promoteur: Prof. Joe Doe\\

Lecteurs : ...

\vspace{\fill}

Année académique 20XX - 20XX

%%%
}%%%

\cleardoublepage
%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%
%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%

\tableofcontents*

\clearpage

%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%
%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%---%%%

\chapter{Introduction}

\section{First section}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Citation of Einstein paper~\cite{Alshehhi2017}.

\section{Second section}
Lorem ipsum.

Lorem ipsum.

\subsection{First subsection}

Lorem ipsum.

\subsection{Second subsection}

Lorem ipsum.

\chapter{Results}

\section{Third section}
Lorem ipsum.

\section{Fourth section}
Lorem ipsum.

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{sample}

\appendix

\chapter{Annexes}*
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod.


\end{document}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would have helped if you had given a complete MWE from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`. It looks as though you might have used the *bianchi* chapterstyle provided by `memoir` for your first example. The `memoir` class provides the *verville* chapterstyle which is close to your desired example (but without any colouring); read Chapter 6 *Document divisions* in the manual (`> texdoc memoir`). Check the code in `memoir.cls` (which will be on your computer somewhere --- try `> kpsewich memoir.cls` to find out where) for the coding for the definition of the *verville*  style. If you don't like it create your own.

Answer (score 0):

The following short modifications should suffice:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\chapterstyle{bianchi}

\renewcommand{\printchaptername}[3]{\printchapternonum}
\renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
  \hrule\vskip\onelineskip \centering \chaptitlefont\textbf{\thechapter\quad#1}\par}

\maxsecnumdepth{subsection} % chapters, sections, and subsections are numbered
\maxtocdepth{subsection} % chapters, sections, and subsections are in the Table of Contents

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents*

\chapter{Introduction}

\section{First section}\lipsum[1]
\section{Second section}\lipsum[2]
\subsection{First subsection}\lipsum[3]
\subsection{Second subsection}\lipsum[4]

\chapter{Results}
\section{Third section}\lipsum[5]
\section{Fourth section}\lipsum[6]

\appendix

\chapter*{Annexes}
\lipsum[5-10]

\end{document}
```

The idea is to make `\printchaptername` be equivalent to `\printchapternonum` which is called by `\chapter*`; the redefinition gobbles 3 arguments that follow `\printchaptername` in the definition of the `bianchi` chapter style and just calls `\printchapternonum`. Additionally, we change `\printchaptertitle` to include `\thechapter\quad` before printing the actual title.